# Hot to handle parent window from clicking on swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple frame with a button.
If I click on the button another frame is going to show up and I don't want to be able clicking the parent frame at all until I am done with the child one.
Does anyone have an idea about this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are speaking about _modal dialog_!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a modal [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) then. Dont use a `JFrame` as the child, use a `JDialog`. Have a look at the constuctors of `JDialog` and pass as an owner the frame, and then set modal to `true` or the [`ModalityType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) to [`APPLICATION_MODAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html#APPLICATION_MODAL) for example.

Like the following code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Parent");

        final JButton button = new JButton("Open child!");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
           final JDialog child = new JDialog(frame, true); //Here you are creating the modal dialog...
           child.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); //The dialog is going to be disposed when you close it.
           child.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Close me...", JLabel.CENTER));
           child.pack();
           child.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
           child.setVisible(true);
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```